# Whitelist.sol - Getting the array of whitelisted addresses

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am writing a token that inherits from Whitelist.sol. I would like to write a function that returns an array of addresses that are whitelisted.

It must be something along the lines of

```
function getWhitelistedUsers() public onlyOwner returns (address[]) {

    address[] memory whitelistedUsers = Roles[ROLE_WHITELISTED].bearer.keys();
    return whitelistedUsers;
}
```

but I am not sure I am on the right path. Can somebody help?

Comment: Please link to `whitelist.sol`, or better yet, include the code here in your question.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/access/Whitelist.sol

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on Ismael's answer.

They provide a way for contracts to check a specific address/role (`hasRole() ... returns(bool)`) but no way to enumerate lists of role members *from the state*. The lists are not discoverable *by other contracts*. The authors don't think it's necessary.

The RBAC (role-based access control) contract emits events when an address/role is added or removed. At line 20 in RBAC.sol:

```
event RoleAdded(address indexed operator, string role);
event RoleRemoved(address indexed operator, string role);
```

Software clients can listen to these event logs and assemble their own reconstructed role lists as needed. As I write this answer, it occurs to me that these logs obfuscate the `operator` because it's `indexed` in both cases.

To accomplish what you want, I'd be tempted to remove `indexed` so the listener can clearly observe the addresses without knowing them in advance. That would give an interested observer everything needed to conveniently construct their own off-chain copy of the on-chain facts. They could then count them, sort them, search them, etc., without further help from the contract.

A case can be made for a "completely discoverable" state. You can accomplish it by creating (and maintaining) lists. You would need to indexes with a delete capability, as describe here. [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)  and here
https://medium.com/@robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-2-ed8d8b4f74ec.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, [bearer](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/access/rbac/Roles.sol#L12) is a mapping and keys are not stored.

```
struct Role {
  mapping (address => bool) bearer;
}
```

If you need to access keys for a mapping you need to explicitely store them in a separate structure.